# How do I continue where I left off in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

So I wrote an ItemReader. When this app is run from the command line again I want to continue reading from where I left off. How do I do that?
I've added spring-task. It seems to track certain things. Does it help with this?
Everything I have read online seems to be talking about restarting the job after a failure. I don't think I have any use for that. I've added all of my stuff into the ExecutionContext. Should I use the JobRepository and start looking around for the last successful execution?

Comment: When you say "When this app is run from the command line again" do you mean you restart the same job instance (using the same identifying parameters) after a failure? Do you use a custom ItemReader or one provided by Spring Batch? Is your item reader stateful (aka it implements `ItemStreamReader` and persists its state in the execution context)? Please share your reader config and add more details about how you start and restart your job to be able to help you.

Comment: I did that right? I said in the post that I do not care about restarting after failure. It's not useful to me. That I do save the stuff into the execution context when update is called. I do implement ItemStreamReader.
The way it works is when the reader has fully read everything it needs to save where it was.

Comment: `I do not care about restarting after failure` What do you mean by "I continue where I left off" if there is no failure? Are you looking for stopping the job somewhere in the middle of execution and resume it "where it left off"? Please explain what are you trying to achieve with an example to understand your use case.

Comment: The reader reads to completion for now. Then later when this job is run again there is more information to read. I need to just keep reading stuff.

Comment: An example is I want to read a log file. When I ran this the first time I read all 100 lines. When I run this the second time there are 200 lines in the file. I need to continue reading the file where I left off.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermark_(data_synchronization)

Comment: Am I using the wrong framework for this? Is this kind of thing just not in peoples minds? How do spring batch jobs know what to process? The basic examples seem to just define jobs that read csv files from specific places. After you do that is that it? new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv") goes into the program. Once that has returned exit code 0 you throw the whole program away? I hate these examples.

Comment: Batch processing is about fixed data sets. In your case, the data set is not fixed. A streaming solution is probably more appropriate. That said, you can still use Spring Batch for that: With a persistent job repository, you can fetch the `read.count` from the last execution and use `FlatFileItemReader#setLinesToSkip` to skip the lines that were already processed in the previous run.

Comment: I pretty much have the same question, Like, I have a perfectly working scheduled spring batch job deployed on Azure. But since it's the Development environment, we frequently deploy on this environment and when we deploy the job breaks down and start new BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to continue from where you left off in the comment.

Mahmoud Ben Hassine explained a good example of applying Spring Batch to your case. He explained that if you want to get the last line you read from the file which can change in size, you can get it from the execution context.
About when to get it from the context, you can use a job execution listener. Let's say, you're basically using the same job parameter. Then `beforeJob` in JobExecutionListener will have the `jobExecution` which have `jobInstance`. You can search for the last job execution by `JobExplorer::getLastJobExecution(JobInstance)`.
Then you simply get the parameter from the execution context and put it in the current context. And you will update it anytime you want, for example, after each write(ItemWriteListener) or after the job finishes(JobExecutionListener).